# What are some reasons a MapReduce job would get to 100% completion and then fail?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This seems to happen to me a lot - the progress bar will say it's 100% completed, but the job will fail.  What are the most common causes of this?

(Not posting code because I want this question to be a generalizable resource to future visitors)

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Is it failing in the cleanup (post-job) code?

Comment: @MattBall: Last time this happened to me, all the logs were erased for some reason, and when I would click on the link for a particular task, it would just direct me to the main application page.  How can I tell if it's failing in the cleanup code?

Comment: Is Reduce job also completes 100% and fail Or only Map job completes 100% and Reduce job at 0%?

Comment: Have a look at this article : https://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/12-ways-to-troubleshoot-a-failed-mapreduce-task/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot always trust the progress bar. It would say that the map is 100% complete but a mapper would still be in progress and is in the process of committing and if something happens wrong there then it would fail. You could have to look at the job log in the UI to get to know where the process is struck.